# Listview с изображениями из sd карты

Tags: android

Здравствуйте.
Я новичок в андройд разработке.
Задача создать кастомный listview с изображениям из sd карты и текстом.
Проблема заключается в подгруздке картинки.
я переопределил адаптер SimpleAdapter и в методе setViewImage выставляю изображение элементу списка

```
public void setViewImage(ImageView v, String value) {
 // value - путь к файлу изображения
 Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(value);
 v.setImageBitmap(b);
}
```

Если передавать путь к изображению на sd карты, то я получаю ошибку при запуске приложении:

> E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

При этом если передавать картинку из ресурсов, то все работает.

```
v.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Comment: Какой путь указываете? Покажите пример.

Comment: Во-первых, я бы рекомендовал вам сначала отправлять переменную `value` в лог, а потом посмотреть его, вдруг путь к файлу неверен. Также вам может потребоваться разрешение `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`.

Comment: добавил в манифест разрешение
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
Вот вывод лога
D/MY_LOG:﹕ /storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140129_180058.jpg
ошибка осталась.
При этом если я добавляю imageview в активити и устанавливаю ему изображение из sd карты, то все работает.

Comment: Есть если я в активити добавляю imageview.
И задаю этому элементу картинку. То она отображается. Проблема не в пути.
outImg = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.outImg);
outImg.setImageDrawable(Drawable.createFromPath("/storage/sdcard0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20140129_180058.jpg"));

Comment: не совсем правильно выразился. Заработало, с отдельным элементом. Но не с кастомным списком.

Comment: Ошибка какая-то такая... Очень может быть, что связанна с эмулятором вообще. BitmapFactory.decodeFile(value) возвращает null, когда не может декодировать файл, соответственно setImageBitmap кинул бы NullPointerException. Дабы сэкономить время и избежать танцев с бубном в AndroidManifest.xml, попробуй отладить программу на физическом устройстве.

Comment: я отлаживаюсь на физическом устройстве.

Comment: Скриншот в студию!

Answer (score 1):

> E/Trace﹕ error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)

Просто игнорируйте эту ошибку. Она возникает при запуске любого приложения (по крайней мере у меня). Если же у вас вместо ImageView выходят белые/чёрные квадраты, то убедитесь, что открываемое изображение имеет размер меньше, чем 3000x3000. Каждый раз декодировать битмап - плохо для памяти. Тем более, что вы декодируете его очень много раз (при прокрутке списка) и даже не используете конфиг RGB_565 для уменьшения потребления памяти. Если вы используете мелкие значки, то я вам настоятельно рекомендую не декодировать *всю* картинку сразу, а [запросить *thumbnail* у системы](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5630543).

**UPD** Написал вам адаптер. Прошу строго не придираться, так как писал на коленке.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
ArrayList<Item> list;
ListView listview;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle s)
{
    super.onCreate(s);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    list = new ArrayList<Item>();
    list.add(new Item("Text", "Val", "сюда укажи путь к файлу"));

    listview = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.listvew);
    listview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.item, list));
}

class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    ArrayList<Item> data;
    Context c;
    int layout_id;

    public MyAdapter(Context ctx, int layout, ArrayList<Item> l)
    {
        super(ctx, layout, l);
        c = ctx;
        layout_id = layout;
        data = l;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, View parent)
    {
        View row = View.inflate(c, layout_id, null);

        TextView name = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_text);
        name.setText(data.get(position).text);

        TextView val = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_val);
        val.setText(data.get(position).val);

        ImageView img = (ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.item_image);

        Cursor cursor = MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.queryMiniThumbnails(
            c.getContentResolver(), Uri.fromFile(new File(data.get(position).path)),
            MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND,
            null );
        if( cursor != null && cursor.getCount() > 0 ) {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            String uri = cursor.getString( cursor.getColumnIndex( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA ) );
            img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(uri)); //тут декодируем уже маленькое изображение
        }

        return row;
    }
}

class Item
{
    public String text = "";
    public String val = "";
    public String path = "";

    public Item(String _text, String _val, String _path)
    {
        this.text = _text;
        this.val = _val;
        this.path = _path;
    }
}
}


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" <!-- Вот это пихните в res/layout -->
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/item_image"
    android:layout_width="96px"
    android:layout_height="96px" />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48px" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_val"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="48px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: код
http://rusfolder.com/39985697

Comment: И всё-таки я склоняюсь к тому, что изображение слишком большое. Сейчас я напишу вам адаптер, подождите :)

Comment: Огромное спасибо. Действительно была проблема в размере изображения.